# Using MD5 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, md5

I want to use hash to verify email existence. I've tried this code and it somehow doesn't work. Is there any mistake or should I look elsewhere?

The code:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE MD5(email+'*salt*')='*some value*' AND checked='0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `+` to concatenate strings. You use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE MD5(CONCAT(email,'*salt*'))='*some value*' AND checked='0'
```